# How can I render form fields in the same line in Django Template

Tags: django, django-forms

I am iterating and rending the fields of a Django form as:

```
      {% for field in form_empty_layer.visible_fields %}
         {{ field | as_bootstrap }} </br>
       {% endfor %}
```

Is there a way in Django to get not only the field which is currently iterated but also the one after?
And moreover then Continue the iteration? I need to put fields in the same row.
So if for example I have these fields:

```
field_1_a, field_1_b,field_2_a, field_2_b,
```

I need the first two to be in the same line and the other two in the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`{% cycle %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) to render a `<br/>` tag only once in two iterations:

```
{% for field in form_empty_layer.visible_fields %}
    {% cycle False True as even_row silent %}
    {{ field|as_bootstrap }}{% if even_row %}<br/>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or:

```
{% for field in form_empty_layer.visible_fields %}
    {{ field|as_bootstrap }}{% cycle "" "<br/>" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Trying to get the current item and the next item in one iteration would be painful to write, awful to read and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks! I get an error: Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%' Any idea why this is happening. I can not see any } missing.

Comment: You are right, it looks like the modulus operator does not exist. You could create it, but it would be actually better to use the `{% cycle %}` template tag. I update my answer.